Do superconductors have an inner magnetisation?
When applying a magnetic field to a (type I) superconductor, the $B$-field vanishes in its interior. Often I read that the inner $H$-field does not vanish due to the magnetisation of the superconductor and $M=-H$ (neglecting shape effects).
However, usually, local magnetisation is understood as being caused by local microscopic currents (e.g., magnetisation is introduced into the Maxwell-equations that way). And I think for type I superconductors there is only a real current at the boundary of the body and therefore inside the superconductor $M=H=0$. Also when assuming a homogeneously magnetised body, the inner magnetisation currents cancel out and only a surface magnetisation current remains, but in this case there is a magnetisation associated to the inner magnetisation currents.

I just realized that this question is very analogous to “Do metals have an inner Polarisation when brought into an electric field?” https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438442/polarization-density-inside-perfect-conductor-placed-in-an-external-electric-fie
